# XPages - At automatic Logout set ReasonType in $$LoginUserForm

Tags: authentication, caching, xpages

I'm a newbie in XPages und I try to learn.. ;-)

I use a timeout to logout the user and to redirect to the login site ($$LoginUserForm).

```
URL + "?Logout&redirectto=" + Url + "?opendatabase&login";
```

Got it form the site and Notesin9.
[text](http://notesspeak.blogspot.com/2014/06/force-your-expired-xpage-to-return-to.html)

And I set the XPage Cache-Control to no-store to prevent the user to go back.

As described here.
[text](https://linqed.eu/2011/11/23/the-order-of-events-in-xpages/%5Btext%5D(https://stackoverflow.com))

This works fine so far.

What I'd like to do is ...

Set the field reasontype in my $$LoginUserForm to "3" which means the login is expired.

[text](https://help.hcltechsw.com/domino/10.0.1/conf_customizingthehtmlloginform_t.html)

Is it possible to use a html command (as shown above) to set a field in the $$LoginUserForm?

Kind regards
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

You can always read the querystring of a HTML form add add the information as default value into a field.

Using @Formula @URLQuerystring("redirectto") to get the redirectto param into a field.

Comment: That's the right direction, thank you. But how can I create a url with query?

URL + "?Logout&redirectto=" + Url + "?opendatabase&login&reason=3";

doesn't work. The browser kills the "&reason=3".

Comment: My Code: var thisUrl = window.location.pathname;var finalPath = thisUrl + "?Logout&redirectto=" + thisUrl + "?opendatabase&reasonid=3&Login"; 
If I print the finalPath to console it includes the argument reasonid. But when then browser runs the link the argument is missing.
Is the link wrong?

Comment: If the URL in redirectto contains parameters, this is the reason.
You should escape the url before you add it as parameter.

E.g.
var thisUrl = escape( window.location.pathname );

Comment: I tried it in that way but sadly it doesn't work for me. var thisUrl = escape(window.location.pathname);var finalPath = thisUrl + "?Logout&redirectto=" + thisUrl + "?opendatabase&reasonid=3&Login";setAutoRefresh(15000, finalPath)